# Saving the points from my object individually as their correct type

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, mapping

This is my second post and i am into the last days of my internship and this is nearly my last problem and task to solve

I have a graph, as agraphviz file,  with a lot of items in it
each item looks like this, there are a few variations but we stay at this

```
Item1434 [label=<
template: "single_multiChoice"<br/>
text.de: "Wählen Sie Antwort A aus."<br/>
text.en: "Select answer A."<br/>
answers: [1]<br/>
endOfPhaseItem: true <br/>
>]
```

in my typescript file im looging this whole tree for their nodes and connections and my object logs as

```
Item1434
single_multiChoice
{
template: '"single_multiChoice"',
'text.de': '"Wählen Sie Antwort A aus."',
'text.en': '"Select answer A."',
answers: '[1]',
endOfPhaseItem: 'true'
}
```

and my task or problem is:

The point is that the fields from the label should be saved individually in the attributes object. So, for example, `attributes.template` should be "freitextTemplate" in the example. And the data type should be correct, for example an array or a number.

This is all done for an End to End Cypress Test, to check if the tree works properly and the correct item is following.

How i log in my console so far:

```
const attributes: { [line: string]: string | boolean | string[] | number[] } ={};
splitting.forEach((row) => {
const key = row.substring(0, row.indexOf(":"))
const value = row.substring(row.indexOf(":") +1).trim()
attributes[key] = value
}); 
console.log(attributes);
```

since my contact person, with whom i worked closely on the project, is away on a business trip and i am now on my own, i am making very slow progress

if you need any more information i may provide them to you.

thanks for any help or tips or ideas, im kinda out of them

i tried to define every row as a const but i may have made something wrong or not complete so i erased everything for the moment.